# how to install porto quick start package in godaddy?

Tags: magento2, theme

I am trying to install Porto quick start package in GoDaddy server but it redirects to another page.
please anyone can help me?

Comment: already installed its work fine for me. can you share more info which page you are redirecting?

Comment: thank you Sanju antala. i copied all quick start files of porto in to root folder in godaddy as hosting serve. i tried to install  then it is redirected to another page

Comment: please guide me how to install the porto theme. actually i am successfully installed  magento 2.2.4 in server and copied the porto  theme files.

Comment: have you  share screen shot please?